# props are not passed correctly to getInitialProps() when refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a page that will show details about a contract that has already deployed to test net. If you enter the page from its above page, everything is showing correctly. However, once I refresh the page, props (a contract address) are not passed correctly to this page.

```
import react, { Component } from "react";
import Layout from "../../components/layout";
import Campaign from "../../campaign";
import { Card, Grid, Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import web3 from "../../web3";
import ContributeForm from "../../components/ContributeForm";
import {Link} from '../../routes'

class CampaignShow extends Component {

  static async getInitialProps(props) {
    const campaign = Campaign(props.query.address);
    const address = props.query.address;
    const summary = await campaign.methods.getSummary().call();

    return {
      address,
      minimumContribution: summary[0],
      balance: summary[1],
      requestsCount: summary[2],
      approversCount: summary[3],
      manager: summary[4]
    };
  }

  renderCards() {


     const {
       balance,
       manager,
       minimumContribution,
       requestsCount,
       approversCount
     } = this.props;

    const items = [
      {
        header: manager,
        meta: "Address of Manager",
        description:
          "The manager created this campaign and can create requests to withdraw money",
        style: { overflowWrap: "break-word" }
      },
      {
        header: minimumContribution.toNumber(),
        meta: "Minimum Contribution (wei)",
        description:
          "You must contribute at least this much wei to become an approver"
      },
      {
        header: requestsCount.toString(),
        meta: "Number of Requests",
        description:
          "A request tries to withdraw money from the contract. Requests must be approved by approvers"
      },
      {
        header: approversCount.toString(),
        meta: "Number of Approvers",
        description:
          "Number of people who have already donated to this campaign"
      },
      {
        header: web3.utils.fromWei(balance.toString(), "ether"),
        meta: "Campaign Balance (ether)",
        description:
          "The balance is how much money this campaign has left to spend."
      }
    ];

    return <Card.Group items={items} />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <h3>Campaign Show</h3>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.Row>
            <Grid.Column width={10}>{this.renderCards()}</Grid.Column>

            <Grid.Column width={6}>
              <ContributeForm address = {this.props.address} />
            </Grid.Column>
          </Grid.Row>

          <Grid.Row>
            <Grid.Column>
              <Link route={`/campaigns/${this.props.address}/requests`}>
                <a>
                  <Button primary>View Requests</Button>
                </a>
              </Link>
            </Grid.Column>
          </Grid.Row>
        </Grid>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

export default CampaignShow;
```

When refreshing the page, the page should correctly acquire the props and display the details of the contract.

Comment: From the `next.js` README: "For the initial page load, `getInitialProps` will execute on the server only. `getInitialProps` will only be executed on the client when navigating to a different route via the `Link` component or using the routing APIs." It sounds like `getInitialProps` isn't working as expected on the server side. Are there any logs? If not, you might consider adding a console.log to test where things go wrong.

Comment: Hi backtick! I printed out console log of `props.query.address` and when I first loaded this page from one page above, it worked totally fine, it printed out the address I expected. But when I refresh the page, it printed out undefined, which indicated that getInitialProps is not retrieving any information from props.query.address. You mentioned that "getInitialProps will only be executed on the client when navigating to a different route via the Link component", I am now wondering if when I refresh a page, I do not navigate to a different route, instead, I stay on the same page.

Comment: Yes, refreshing the page is equivalent to the "initial page load" event described in the quote from the docs.

Answer (score 0):

When you route from one page to another your page through click/link then you will get the props from the client side. if you want the same should work when you are refreshing the page then you have to set up the server side routes and pass the query params from server to that page then it will work as you expect. You can use this plugin 
https://github.com/fridays/next-routes